# Swift 5 not reading EAN 13 barcodes

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code

In swift 5 I can capture QR codes fine, but this fails to detect EAN13 barcodes. Can anyone point me in the right direction, thanks

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    if metadataObjects.count != 0 {

        if let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        {
            if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr {

                do something

            }

            else if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean13 {

                do something else

            }         

      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `.ean13` to the list of metadata object types when initialising your capture session?

For example:

```
    let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    
     if captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
         captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)
         metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
         metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr, .ean13]
     }
```